# Google Play Console, Private App

Tags: android, google-play

I'm close to publish a little app on Google Play Store, but first I want to keep it secret and to give access to it only to certain people.

I bought the 25$ account and filled all the required informations for my app, but It seems that we must have a "production|public" APK to be able to create closed Alpha|Beta one.

But in my case I only want a closed Alpha|Beta and no public version.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not true. An app can have an alpha or beta without a release version. (I just tested that)

Comment: Oh well, it's true !